# How can I hide a login form from people that are logged in?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
}
else
{
   echo '<div id="DLogin1" style="position:absolute;left:76px;top:549px;width:183px;height:196px;z-index:22;">
<form name="loginform" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" id="loginform">
<input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="loginform"/>
<table id="TLogin1">
<tr>
   <td class="header">Log In</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="label"><label for="username">User Name:</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="row"><input class="input" name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="label"><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="row"><input class="input" name="password" type="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="row"><input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme"/><label for="rememberme">Remember me</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom"><input class="button" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" id="login"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>';
}
?>
```

This is what i have so far, but it doesn't do what i think it should be doing...

Basically, I think that it should check to see if the username is set. If it is, nothing happens, otherwise it will make the login box appear.

How is this a duplicate?

Comment: Can you tell us what *is* happening?

Comment: This script doesn't appear to ever set the session, so I'd expect it to always show the login form.

Comment: Have You Started The Session In This Page? `session_start();`

Comment: every script that uses the session must start with `session_start()` in fact it is simpler to add this statement in a file you included/require in all of your scripts

Comment: What is happening is the login box is being showed regardless. yes i have started the session. This was working before i have tried to make the login box invisible for users.